# How to make three different bar charts of similar type clustered in the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need to map my Erosion values for different levels of tillage (colomns) with three levels of soil depth (rows (A1, A2, A3)). I want all of this to be shown as a barchart in a single plot.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
a<- matrix(c(1:36), byrow = T,  ncol = 4)
rownames(a)<-(c("A1","B1","C1","A2","B2","C2","A3","B3","C3"))
colnames(a)<-(c("Int_till", "Redu_till", "mulch_till", "no_till"))

barplot(a[1,], xlab = "A1", ylab = "Erosion") 
barplot(a[4,], xlab = "A2", ylab = "Erosion")
barplot(a[7,], xlab = "A3", ylab = "Erosion")
##I want these three barchart side by side in a single plot
## for comparison 

### and need similar plots for all the "Bs" and "Cs"  
### Lastly, i want these three plots in the same page.
```

I have seen people do similar things using "fill" in ggplot (for lines) and specifying the factor which nicely separates the chart for different categories but I tried doing it but always run into error maybe because my data is continuous.

If any body could help me with these two things.. It will be a great help. I will appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are doing this in `ggplot`, can have it with `facet_wrap` or in. `base R`, change the `par`

Comment: you can do `par(mfrow = c(3, 1))` and then run the `barplot` statements

Comment: Do you need `library(reshape2); library(ggplot2);> melt(a) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Var1)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))`

Answer (score 1):

Set `mfcol` to specify a 3x3 grid and then for each row generate its bar plot.  Also, you could consider adding the `barplot` argument `ylim = c(0, max(a))` so that all graphs use the same Y axis.  `title` and `mtext` can be used to set the overall title and various margin text as we do below.  See `?par`, `?title` and `?mtext` for more information.

```
opar <- par(mfcol = c(3, 3), oma = c(0, 3, 0, 0))
for(r in rownames(a)) barplot(a[r, ], xlab = r, ylab = "Erosion")
par(opar)

title("My Plots", outer = TRUE, line = -1)
mtext(LETTERS[1:3], side = 2, outer = TRUE, line = -1, 
  at = c(0.85, 0.5, 0.17), las = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you this worked out wonderfully well. I was able to do all As in first row, all Bs in second row and all Cs in third Row. Could you please tell me how i can label each row as just "A", "B" or "C" in this graph? So that in the left hand side of the graph there are labels like "A", "B" and "C" in each row. Also how can i add title to this whole plot?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ggplot`

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
melt(a) %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Var1)) + 
         geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
              position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) + 
         facet_wrap(~ Var1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like this one as well. I asked this question above as well, how i can label each row as just "A", "B" or "C" in this graph? So that in the left hand side of the graph there are labels like "A", "B" and "C" in each row. I also tried adding title using    ( + labs( title = "title")) but the title only comes in the side. How could i fix this?