# using mfrow in R : how do you give each subplot a different y-label and the x-axis one label

Tags: r, plot, visualization, lapply, boxplot

I am working in R and I have to make many boxplots. This is a visualization of group differences. I want to relabel the x-axis to only have one title instead of five (one for each subplot). My biggest problem is that I also want the y-axis of all the subplots to have different labels.

This is what I tried so far:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
lapply(NEW8[,c("gawayf",    "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf")],
       function(x) boxplot(x ~ NEW8$PAPA_p4_adhd,col=rainbow(2),
                           names=c("CN","ADHD"),
                           ylab=c("gawayf", "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf")))
```

All the y-labels are added to each subplots so each subplots has 5 lines of y-axis labels (gawayf, humf, sgamef, swtoyf, kissf), and each plot says what data was used to create the boxplot (`PAPA_P4_ADHD`). 
I want each plots to only have the corresponding y-axis label and the x-axis to have 1 label for all five plots.

This is my current output:

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: So only one of your five plots should have an x-axis label? Try this: use `Map(function(x, i) { your_code_here; }, NEW8[,c(...)], 1:5)` and in your function, include `xlab = if (i==1) labelhere else NULL`.

Comment: There is an example of that here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017055/how-to-make-three-different-bar-charts-of-similar-type-clustered-in-the-same-plo/58017355#58017355  It has a different xlab for each plot but it works the same for ylab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `lapply` try `mapply` - that will allow to pass different argument to each function call:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
myBox <- function(x, y, ...) boxplot(x ~ y, col=rainbow(2), names=c("CN", "ADHA"), ...)
mapply(myBox,
       x    = NEW8[,c("gawayf",    "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf")],
       y    = list(NEW8$PAPA_p4_adhd),  # we make this a list so it has length(1)
       ylab = c("gawayf", "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf"),
       xlab = ""  # empty x-lab
       )
```

For x-lab you will have to do a trick - start a new empty plot that overlays all of the plots, and only add x-axis:

```
par(fig=c(0,1,0,1), oma=c(0,0,0,0), mar=par("mar"), new=TRUE)
plot.new()
title(xlab="my x-axis")
```

NOTE: I didn't try to run this code myself, if anything here doesn't work - please leave a comment and will try to address it.

Comment: It didnt work I got this error: Error in (function (x, y)  : 
  unused arguments (ylab = dots[[3]][[1]], xlab = dots[[4]][[1]])

Comment: Thank you, the mapply worked after a few edits.                                                 
The following script works:                                                          
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
myBox <- function(x, y, ylab, xlab) boxplot(x ~ y, col=rainbow(2), names=c("CN", "ADHD"),ylab=ylab, xlab=xlab)
mapply(myBox,
       x    = NEW8[,c("gawayf",    "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf")],
       y    = list(NEW8$PAPA_p4_adhd),  # we make this a list so it has length(1)
       ylab = c("gawayf", "humf", "sgamesf",  "swtoyf",   "kissf"),
       xlab = ""  # empty x-lab
)

Comment: @Lyly glad to hear it works now! To mark this question properly as "solved" - please consider accepting the answer by clicking the "accept" checkmark.